# Can't resume download from Sonatype Nexus

Tags: http, curl, nexus, sonatype

We have a war file in Nexus.  I can download the artifact just fine using curl.  But if this download is interrupted, and I add the '-C -' option to curl, the resume fails with '(33) HTTP server doesn't seem to support byte ranges. Cannot resume.'

The resume seems to receive the initial 200 header again from the server, rather than a 206 header.  Using similar '--continue' options with wget produces a failure as well, indicating it's trying to start over.

This is with Sonatype Nexus OSS 2.12.1-01, and curl 7.29.0.

I found references to some bug with resumed downloads fixed in 2.11.2, so I think there's something misconfigured here.

Could I get some help in how to debug what isn't happening and correct it, please?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as both Nexus Repository Manager 2.x and 3.x support resumed downloads. The issue you mention (https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-7903) was merged prior to 2.12 and as such it would be included.

Can you try with some of the syntax on curl as mentioned in the ticket? 
Specifically the example of a simulated partial request and resume with curl and wget.

```
curl -o test.jar -r 0-8 http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
wget -O test.jar -c http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/asm/asm/3.1/asm-3.1.jar
```

Note that we tested today with curl 7.43.0 on a Maven repository.

Are you using a different repository format maybe?